# How to sort results within a filtered dropdown in amphtml?

Tags: amp-html

I have a flight booking form containing the typical "From" and "To" countries. The list of countries loaded from a JSON endpoint in the following format:

```
airportList": [
  {
    "countryName": "Finland",
    "airportName": "Helsinki Vantaa",
    "airportCode": "HEL",
    "cityName": "Helsinki",
    "countryCode": "FI",
    "cityCode": "HEL"
  },
  {...},
  {...}
]
```

When I input "sin" for example in the From field, I filter the JSON and show the suggested values in a dropdown. The JSON is filtered using several keys in the JSON including countryName, airportName, cityName and airportCode.

Is there a way I can sort the priority of the results shown? Eg. if I search for "sin", I want to see the list of cities first before the list of airport names containing this term.

Current filtering logic I'm using:

```
<input type="text" [value]="formValues.fromAirport" value="" 
on="input-debounced:AMP.setState({location:{sourceItems:airports.airportList.filter(x=> (!event.value 
|| x.cityName.toLowerCase().indexOf((event.value||'').toLowerCase()) > -1 
|| x.airportName.toLowerCase().indexOf((event.value||'').toLowerCase()) > -1 
|| x.countryName.toLowerCase().indexOf((event.value||'').toLowerCase()) > -1 
|| x.airportCode.toLowerCase().indexOf((event.value||'').toLowerCase()) > -1 )) }})">
```